# Replicated docs count on solr

Tags: solr, replication

I am replicating docs from master to slave. Polling interval is 60 sec. How can I get the count of docs replicated in latest replication.

Answer (score 0):

There is Admin Page for Replication. Look into section "Current Replication Status" section
More about it here: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrReplication

Comment: It is very informative, but I m looking for the exact file count in poll interval eg. File indexed in last Poll: 1234.